# C++/Java: Why are people so passionate about vectors/arrays in Stack Overflow Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I noticed in the "Java Language" and "C++ Language" on Stack Overflow Documentation that there is a significant amount of upvotes on arrays/vectors... Why?

Considering it is more about being instructions (I think?), why is there so much passion about something so simple? Why not about C++ features?

Comment: May be they are *passionate about arrays*.. Or they could know arrays quite well (and hence decided to write about 'em). May be they think that arrays are misunderstood.

Comment: ^I think we found one passionate about arrays... I suppose what really piqued my curiosity isn't that X was being written about more than Y, but why such a large group of very smart people become focused on what might be a simple topic; I'm not that smart, so maybe I just don't get it.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 It's not really a large group and they could be only smart, not very smart for all we know. Maybe C++ Vectors is an often used concept which is still simple enough so that it is easy to write a bit about them while still also being useful to read it actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what is known as "[bikeshedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/323179)". Though the term is often used for naming, it applies here.

The idea is that if you have a group of people who are debating something, the topics that will get the most interest are those that the most number of people understand. Not everyone understands the essential needs for architecture or different construction materials. But everyone understands colors. So when dealing with, for example, a bikeshed, you'll get more debate around what color it is than around what it's made of. Even though clearly its construction materials actually matter more.

Of course, this is not *just* bikeshedding. Docs.SO couples that with the fact that highly upvoted examples are what you see *first*. And topics are ranked based on the number of upvotes on their examples. So everyone who opens up the documentation page for Java will see the arrays topic first.

The winners keep on winning, and the losers get nothing.

Basically, Docs.SO's ordering, coupled with general bikeshedding, makes it very likely that the first thing you see on a page will be the least interesting piece of information.

Comment: tl;DR, if you want to read really interesting topics go to the last page. :D